# How to call a function using a th:each object as its parameter

Tags: spring-thymeleaf

I have a "listInvoicesForm" object that contains a public function below:

`public boolean isParsedFileAvailable(InvoiceIndex invoiceIndex) { . . .  }`

In my Thymeleaf page, I need to call this function and pass in the invoiceIndex object that is coming from the th:each loop. I tried this

`th:if=*{!isParsedFileAvailable(${invoiceIndex})}`

But it fail with the following error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [!isParsedFileAvailable(${invoiceIndex})] @24: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'`

My thymeleaf code looks like below:

```
<table  th:object="${listInvoicesForm}">
. . .
<tr th:each="invoiceIndex, rowStat : *{invoiceIndexes}" >
   . . .
    <td align="center" width="5%">
        <span th:if="*{!isParsedFileAvailable(${invoiceIndex})}" th:text="-">- (No Parsed File)</span>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can't mix *{} with ${} (unless it is a preprocessing expressing **${}**).

I changed my th:if condition to only use ${} and it works:

```
<span th:if="${!listInvoicesForm.isParsedFileAvailable(invoiceIndex)}" th:text="-">- (No Parsed File)</span>
```